# async function not executing in Infinite Loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I have a *trySwitch()* `async` function which I want to run in a infinite loop and stop when the input is not in my cases.

```
async function trySwitch () {
    let input = Number(readline.question())

    switch (input) {
        case 1:
            await insertBooks();
            break;
        case 2:
            await findBooks();
            break;
        case 3:
            await updateBooks();
            break;
        case 4:
            await deleteBooks();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

while (true) {
    trySwitch()
        .then((result) => { if (result === false) {
                return console.log('...done.')
            }
        })
        .catch(console.error);
}
```

But the while loop is not waiting for the async function to execute and starting again immediately after the input is given. All the inside functions (insert, find, update, delete) need to be async.
Can someone guide me how to handle this?

Comment: You need to `await trySwitch(...)`, otherwise the `while()` loop runs forever before any of your `.then()` handlers get to run.

Answer (score 2):

You should await trySwitch in your while loop

```
while (true) {
     try{
        const result  = await trySwitch();
     }catch(err){
       console.error(err);
    }
```

this will wait until your function executes, unlike then will run in the background.

Comment: This worked. Initially it didn't but I realised that insertBooks() is also using .then(), updated it with try-catch and it fixed the issue.